# Does "Outlook Mail REST API" include access to corporate MS exchange server email?

Tags: exchange-server, office365, outlook-restapi

I found in the documentation of the "Outlook Mail REST API" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations) that it applies to "Exchange Online | Office 365 | Hotmail.com | Live.com | MSN.com | Outlook.com | Passport.com".

Does the "Exchange Online" piece relate to the "Corporate Exchange-based email that does not use Office 365" that is mentioned in the table here (https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Sign-in-to-Outlook-Web-App-e08eb8ac-ac27-49f4-a400-a47311e1ee7e) or are there other options to integrate with on-premises (Microsoft Exchange Server) corporate email?

Comment: Micosoft graph changes the game, the answer would most likely be to use that instead. (Although the question is quite old)

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook REST APIs are not yet fully supported for on-premise Exchange installations.  A subset of the REST APIs are present in Exchange 2016 today, but we will be bringing much more functionality to on-premise Exchange 2016 REST APIs in the near-future.

In the meantime, if you really need to connect to on-premise Exchange the main option you have is Exchange Web Services and Exchange Active Sync.

Comment: when do you think will this available for on-premise?

Comment: Update on REST configuration for Hybrid Deployments:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/26/on-premises-architectural-requirements-for-the-rest-api/