# How to connect to outlook from browser (internet explorer)

Tags: javascript, email, internet-explorer, outlook

So this is what I need for my customer

From my secure intranet webapplication the user can select several files. Somehow (browser plugin/add-on, JavaScript, whatever) the user can start outlook to compose a new mail. The selected files have to be attached to the composed mail. To make things even more interesting, the filenames of the attached files have to be altered (the file version has to be added to the filename).
It must work with Outlook 2013 and Internet Explorer 11.

I don't want the mail to be created in the browser and then be send from the server, since I want the user to have full control on the composed mail and have them use all the features of Outlook.

What would be the right technique(s) to accomplish this?

Comment: how if use outlook RestAPI ? https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/php

Comment: I need a solution for outlook om premis (Exchange). I might be able to use the RestAPI. Alternative api's are Exchange Web Services or Exchange Active Sync. See this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885336/does-outlook-mail-rest-api-include-access-to-corporate-ms-exchange-server-emai)
The best thing I can come up with is creating an email and save to the users drafts folder.
Then maybe I can open a link to outlook web access.
Or do you know a better way to use the api in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically create an EML file (MIME) and give the user a link to it. Outlook will be able to open the message with the HTM body, recipients, attachments, etc. prepopulated.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try to use this into your javascript**

mailto:email@domain.com?subject=file&body=P.F.A&attachment='filepath/filename.extention'

Comment: Seems not to work, probably because Outlook won't be able to access the file to attach. Besides that, the attachment names can't be altered this way.

Comment: Digged a little further. Attachments using mailto links are not supported since Outlook 2007, so even without the security issue it won't work.

Comment: See mailto protocol at msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737.aspx